# Qt QCalendarWidget QSS Styling

Tags: qt, qt4, qtstylesheets

I know there's no support for `QCalendarWidget` `QSS` styling but does anyone know some workarounds for changing the color of sections `1` and `2` of the `QCalendarWidget`? (the light blue for section `1` and white for section `2`)

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've examined `QCalendarWidget` [source code](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/widgets/qcalendarwidget.cpp) and found the solution.

`QCalendarWidget` internally has a model and a view to display days. `QCalendarModel` has a `formatForCell(int, int)` function that returns `QTextCharFormat` for a given cell. Returning format is the result of merging `QCalendarView` palette data, a format for current day (saturday and sunday are shown in red) and a format for current date, which can be set using `QCalendarWidget::setDateTextFormat` function.

Actually an item's background is:

```
format.setBackground(pal.brush(cg, header ? QPalette::AlternateBase : QPalette::Base));
```

- `pal` is a `QCalendarView`'s palette;
- `cg` is a [color group](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qpalette.html#ColorGroup-enum);
- `header` is true when the current cell is a header cell (section 1 in your example)

So, all you need is to set your custom palette to that internal `QCalendarView`. In the source code we can find that `QCalendarView` object has a name "qt_calendar_calendarview" which we can use:

```
QCalendarWidget *c = new QCalendarWidget;

QTableView *view = c->findChild<QTableView*>("qt_calendar_calendarview");
if (view)
{
    QPalette pal = view->palette();
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::red);
    pal.setColor(QPalette::AlternateBase, Qt::green);
    view->setPalette(pal);
}
```

In my example section 1 will be red and section 2 will be green.
Additionally you can set colors for every [color group](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qpalette.html#ColorGroup-enum) of you palette to get the widget you like when it's active, inactive etc.

Answer (score 3):

Area "1" customization:

```
QTextCharFormat format;
format.setForeground(QBrush(Qt::blue));
format.setBackground(QBrush(Qt::red);
ui->calendarWidget->setHeaderTextFormat(format);
```

Area "2" QSS CSS:

```
QCalendarWidget QAbstractItemView
{
background-color: rgb(192,192,192); /* цвет фона текущего месяца */
selection-background-color: yellow; /* цвет фона выбранного дня */
selection-color: black; /* цвет текста выбранного дня */
}
```

or

```
#qt_calendar_calendarview
{
background-color: rgb(192,192,192); /* цвет фона текущего месяца */
selection-background-color: yellow; /* цвет фона выбранного дня */
selection-color: black; /* цвет текста выбранного дня */
}
```

, where `#qt_calendar_calendarview` - object's name from `d->m_view->setObjectName(QLatin1String("qt_calendar_calendarview"));` in `qcalendarwidget.cpp`