# QCalendarWidget selection color

Tags: c++, qt, calendar, selection

I have a `QCalendarWidget` and some days of month are colored (for example holidays are red). When I select a day which is colored, selection clears the color and I can't see it's original color. But when I deselect that day - color is back. Please see in pictures.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to keep color even if a day is selected? I know that there is a way to do this for `QTableView` with delegates, but I can't find anything like this for `QCalendarWidget`. Any Ideas? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to the internal `QTableView` object of your calendar widget like this:

```
QCalendarWidget *c = new QCalendarWidget;

QTableView *view = c->findChild<QTableView*>("qt_calendar_calendarview");
if (view)
{
    view->setItemDelegate(new MySuperCalendarDelegate);
}
```

Then you can use a custom delegate that will set proper background and foreground colors.

Also you can check [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14730459/1465625) on `QCalendarWidget` styling.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's more than a year, if I understood the question correctly, I think I found a better solution to this. In my case, every time a date is selected, I set the date to yellow color doing the following:

```
QTextCharFormat fmt;
fmt.setBackground(Qt::yellow);
m_ui->calender->setDateTextFormat(date, fmt);
```

and that very time I also set the stylesheet of the `QCalenderWidget` like this:

```
setStyleSheet("QTableView{selection-background-color: yellow}")
```

If I need to de-select, I set the date color to the original, which is white and also do the following:

```
setStyleSheet("QTableView{selection-background-color: yellow}")
```

This works great for me.