# How to use Delegate with QCalendarWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I need modify the delegate in a `QCalenderWidget`. I want to change the background-color of cell when the user select a specific day.

I would like getting a simple example.

Comment: You may want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643063/qcalendarwidget-selection-color

Answer (score 1):

You could use `QWidget::setStyleSheet(const QString & styleSheet)` and set `selection-background-color` value:

```
auto calendar = new QCalendarWidget(this);
calendar->setStyleSheet("selection-background-color:black");
```

Comment: I need use Delegate because i have change the cells that have meet with de teacher, I look for in the DataBase.